set object has no attribute 'is_empty'
The following  code in sage runs well:
myset = Set([1, 2, 3, 4])
myset.is_empty()

Output: False
We can implement it below link (SageMath online cell).
https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLrSxOLbENTi3RiDbUUTDSUTDWUTCJ1eTlygVJ6GUWx6fmFpRUamgCAAP1DIU=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==
But the following code gives us an error.
my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4}
print(my_set)
my_set.is_empty()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 5
      3 my_set = {Integer(1), Integer(2), Integer(3), Integer(4)}
      4 print(my_set)
----> 5 my_set.is_empty()

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'is_empty'

Why do the two sets give completely different results, even though they are both sets?

Thanks to all the helpful comments from users in the comments section.  I initially mixed up SageMath(though it is based python) and Python. As darren said, in sage Set is a class. Whereas set (lower case s) is a method that takes a list as an argument as @jonrsharpe pointed out.

because set takes one argument that is a list...

What do you think capital-s Set is? The set a literal makes indeed has no such method.

also set dies not have the method is_empty.

Sorry, I got Sage and Python mixed up. Sage can actually handle it. See https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLrSxOLbENTi3RiDbUUTDSUTDWUTCJ1eTlygVJ6GUWx6fmFpRUamgCAAP1DIU=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ== and  https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/sets/sage/sets/set.html#sage.sets.set.Set_object.is_empty

python can also handle it.  if you make a custom class with the method is_empty...

@darren Thank you, I understand now, although unfortunately, I received two (or possibly more) opposing votes.

the views are consistent.  Set would be a class. Whereas set (lower case s) is a method that takes a list as an argument as @jonrsharpe pointed out,
